# Passar valores do Javascript para uma classe Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, funções

Preciso criar alguns botões dinamicamente no c# e passar para eles algum evento, que ao clicar-Los passe dois valores para uma variável de select para trazer  quantidade x de linhas do mesmo

a classe com o select

```
public DataSet MaxId()
{
    cldBancoDados cldBancoDados = new cldBancoDados();

    StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder();
    strQuery.Append("SELECT ");
    strQuery.Append("MAX (ID_OFERTA) ");
    strQuery.Append("FROM TB_OFERTA");
    return cldBancoDados.RetonarDataSet(strQuery.ToString());
}

public DataSet TrazerProdutosDesconto(int a, int b)
{
    cldBancoDados cldBancoDados = new cldBancoDados();

    StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder();
    strQuery.Append("SELECT ");
    strQuery.Append("CONCAT(P.NOME_PRODUTO, ");
    strQuery.Append("CONCAT(CONCAT(' ',P.MARCA_PRODUTO),");
    strQuery.Append("CONCAT(CONCAT(' ',P.DESCRICAO_PRODUTO),");
    strQuery.Append("CONCAT(' ',P.PESO_PRODUTO)))),");
    strQuery.Append("PE.PRECO_PRODUTO, ");
    strQuery.Append("O.DESCONTO, ");
    strQuery.Append("O.DURACAO_OFERTA, ");
    strQuery.Append("P.IMG, ");
    strQuery.Append("LJ.IMG ");
    strQuery.Append("FROM TB_OFERTA O ");
    strQuery.Append("INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTO_ESTOQUE PE ");
    strQuery.Append("ON PE.ID_PRODUTO_ESTOQUE = O.ID_PRODUTO_ESTOQUE ");
    strQuery.Append("INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTO P ");
    strQuery.Append("ON P.ID_PRODUTO = PE.ID_PRODUTO ");
    strQuery.Append("INNER JOIN TB_LOJA LJ ");
    strQuery.Append("ON LJ.ID_LOJA = PE.ID_LOJA ");
    strQuery.Append("WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN " + a + " AND " + b);
    return cldBancoDados.RetonarDataSet(strQuery.ToString());
}
```

no caso preciso passar os tais valores por javascript para as variaveis 'a' e 'b'.

Comment: Se pode associar qualquer botão a um evento isso é muito simples, mas, o seu contexto atual da pergunta não nos diz onde, e muito ampla e pode gerar respostas não apropriadas ao seu modelo. Se poderia por favor colocar um contexto melhor, [editando a sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244398/54880)?

Comment: Eu não sei usar javasjavascript, preciso de uma função  que passe dois valores no ato do click do botão

Comment: Correto, mas, a pergunta mesmo assim é vaga ... impossível saber aonde !!! tinha que ter uma exemplo minimo. desculpas, mas, continua ampla, uma dica se não saber mexer com javascript primeiro pare e vai aprender isso vai ser muito importante!

Comment: editei a pergunta para ficar mais detalhada, espero que alguém possa ajuda